# how to start a flow when a field is changed to a specific value only

Tags: visual-workflow

Trying to create a record triggered flow that updates field2 when field1 (picklist) is changed to a specific value. I also want to ensure that we check that the prior status value is different than the current status value.

[image]

Does this first condition satisfy the need to check that the prior status is different than the current? Or do I need to do a follow up decision element to utilize record__prior? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The above condition should be sufficient for the flow to work. But if you wish to add Record_Prior no need to create another decision you can use it in the start condition only as shown below.

As you are not using formula evaluates to True it is not visible. Can you try to change the Formulas for Conditions from " All conditions are Met (AND)" to "Formula Evaluates to True(New)" as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The first condition satisfies the check for the prior value change.
Also there is no need for decision element.

Requirement : Update field2 when field1 (picklist) is changed.
If the field is on same record which triggering the flow Use Before - Save Flow.
field2 can be update by using update triggering record element in flow.